# Top voters tab is not working correctly on per-site metas

Tags: bug, per-site-meta, pagination, users-page

The top voters tab is not working correctly on per-site metas. If I am on a tab that is not all time voters, and I click to go to page 2, then it sends me to tab 2 of the all time voters. Example: Go to https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=year. Then clicking the 2, it will redirect me to 
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users?page=2&tab=voters, which is tab 2 of the all time voters instead of tab 2 of the year voters.

This does not only happen on meta.math.SE, but also on a lot (probably all) other per-site metas. It does not happen here on meta.SE.